# PHP substring extrac and calulate

Tags: php, exif

I'm using to show exif data of a picture.

this is the code

```
<?php

  $filename = "http://www.rallyfun.net/images/20140921231511_img_7369.jpg";


  $exif = exif_read_data($filename, 0, true);

  echo "Exposure: " . $exif["EXIF"]["ExposureTime"] . " sec.<br />";
  echo "F: " . $exif["EXIF"]["FNumber"] . "<br />";
  echo "ISO: " . $exif["EXIF"]["ISOSpeedRatings"] . "<br />";

?>
```

this is the result:

```
Exposure: 1/6400 sec.
F: 63/10 sec.
ISO: 1000
```

the result is ok except for the aperture: it must be displayed as (in this case) 6.3  so i need to divide the first number (63) with the number after the "/" (10).

how?

Comment: should your second echo read `echo "F: " . $exif["EXIF"]["FNumber"] . " sec.<br />";`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for this.

```
$tmp = explode('/', str_replace(' sec.', '', $exif["EXIF"]["FNumber"]));
echo "F: " . ($tmp[0]/$tmp[1]) . "sec<br />";
```

Comment: @TomSawyer overlooked that indeed. Thought he was echoing the `sec`

Comment: this works! sorry for 'sec' my mistake. i left it when i douplicated the first row.  

this is the complete working code:
      // Get EXIF data
  $exif = exif_read_data($filename, 0, true);

  // Echo the ExposureTime item (and some context)
  echo "Exposure: " . $exif["EXIF"]["ExposureTime"] . " sec.<br />";
   $tmp = explode('/', str_replace('', '', $exif["EXIF"]["FNumber"]));
echo "F: " . ($tmp[0]/$tmp[1]) . "<br />";
  echo "F: " . $exif["EXIF"]["ISOSpeedRatings"] . " ISO<br />";

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
$n = $exif["EXIF"]["FNumber"];
$whole = floor($n);      // 63
$fraction = $n - $whole; // .10

$result=$whole/$fraction;
```

Comment: i'm gettign "Warning: Division by zero" maybe cacuase $n is 63/10 and not 63.10  (slash intesad of point)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to display aperture:

```
preg_match('/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/',$exif["EXIF"]["FNumber"],$m);
if($m[1] && $m[2])
{
    $newaperture = $m[1]/$m[2];
    echo $newaperture;
}
```